# Can a node.js server be named like a directory location?

Tags: node.js, server, directory, port

In node.js how do I create a server accessible with a name not a port?

instead of:

https://example.com:port

this kind of thing:

https://example.com/name/

Comment: In your second case, it's just running on the default port (port 80). You may need elevated priviliges to run a server on port 80, but there's nothing more magical to it than that.

Answer (score 0):

A server (of any kind) is only named by the domain and port in the URL - it not named by the path at all.  The browser parses the URL, takes the domain and port, looks up that domain in DNS to get the IP address, then makes a TCP connection to that specific IP address and port.   So, in your example, that would be:

```
https://example.com:port
```

or

```
https://example.com
```

where the latter just uses the default port of 80.  Only those portions of the URL specify the server that the browser will connect to.  The path is then sent to that server and the server can then decide what it wants to do with that path when it receives the request.

---

That said, there are server-side tools you can use that will handle a request at the above server, look at the path and then forward that request to a different server/port.  This is often called a proxy server.  So, for example, you can run nginx (a pre-built, configurable proxy) that will let you configure that you want a request to `https://example.com/name/` to go to some other host (which you can configure as some other IP address and port).

The browser will connect to `example.com` (which is your proxy) and send the http request for `/name`.  The proxy will receive that request, look at the path, see that it is configured to forward that request to a different host, then connect to that other host, send the request to it, get the response back, then return the response back to the browser.  The browser will not necessarily know that this "forwarding" is going on behind-the-scenes.  It makes a request and gets an answer.